# How to add colour to the American Flag

Tags: colors

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package americanflag;

/**
 *
 * @author abzdino
 */
public class AmericanFlag {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        
String p1 = "* * * * * * ==================================\n * * * * *  ==================================";
  String p2 = "==============================================";
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   System.out.println(p1);
  }
  System.out.println("* * * * * * ==================================");
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   System.out.println(p2);
  }
 }
}// TODO code application logic here
```

I've been asked by my professor to write a Java program to print an American flag on the screen (which is coded above). However, our professor informed us to think outside the box and use colour rather than it be black and white.

Comment: It depends upon the output console. Have you tried ANSI codes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println

Comment: What is ANSI codes ?

Comment: The link in my comment explains them