# with java printf print different colors

Tags: java, colors, printf

I'm trying to print different colors with printf.  I've tried the following:

```
System.out.printf("%s%s%s%s\n","\u001B[31m","abcd","\u001B[30m","xyz");
```

I was expecting abcd to be in red and xyz to be in black but everything is black.

Comment: Your OS is what?

Comment: Does the terminal support color?

Comment: Adding to what @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo has mentioned, it does work in most IDEs (In the past, I have tested it in Eclipse and VSC).

Comment: Related: [How to print color in console using System.out.println?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5762491/10819573)

Comment: @g00se  windows 10 using bluej as ide