# Changing Text Color for Elements in a Java String Array in a Console-Based Application

Tags: java

I'm working on a Java application and I have an array of text strings. I would like to apply different text colors to individual elements within the array. If this is not possible using standard Java libraries, what alternative approaches or libraries can I use to achieve this? I'm interested in methods for changing the text color in a console-based application, and I'm open to suggestions or examples that work across different platforms.

this part, tried and failed:

```
            menu.setMenuOptions(new String[]{"\nWelcome to the Employee Menu." + "\n1. Add a product." + "\n2. Remove a product." + "\n3. Display all products." + "\n4. Log out and return to customer menu." + "\n5. Exit the program."});
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(menu.getMenuOptions()).replace("[", "").replace("]", " "));
```

Comment: [How to print color in console using System.out.println?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5762491)