# Variables assigned to ANSI codes aren't working properly when called in non-main method, displaying the wrong color

Tags: java, methods, colors

I'm new, trying to learn java and I'm making a short text-based game using methods. It's working, but I'm trying to color the text. For example, in the first message, I'm trying to make the text
"Kyle is currently sitting at the breakfast table, reminiscing over times he had milk for his cereal." purple. rather, it prints it as green. Printing color works inside the main method, but suddenly breaks when I call it in other methods.

Here's the declaration of colors in the main method:

```
      //THIS IS BOLD
          String ANSI_BOLD = "\u001B[1m";
      //COLOR RESET CODE
          String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m"; 
      //THIS IS CYAN
          String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
      //THIS IS RED
          String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
      //THIS IS BLACK
          String ANSI_BLACK = "\u001B[30m";
      //THIS IS BLUE
          String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
      //THIS IS GREEN
          String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
      //THIS IS YELLOW
           String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m"; 
      //THIS IS WHITE
          String ANSI_WHITE = "\u001B[37m";
      //THIS IS PURPLE
          String ANSI_PURPLE = "\u001B[35m";`
```

This is defined AFTER the method it's mentioned in, as I don't think i can make methods after the main one. The variables are then called in the method:

```
//first interaction
  public static void StartingInteraction(ArrayList<String> inventory, double money, String ANSI_BOLD, String ANSI_RESET, String ANSI_CYAN, String ANSI_RED, String ANSI_GREEN, String ANSI_YELLOW, String ANSI_PURPLE, String ANSI_BLUE, String ANSI_WHITE, String ANSI_BLACK, Scanner scanner01){

  
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    invMoneyUpdate(inventory, money, ANSI_BOLD, ANSI_RESET, ANSI_CYAN, ANSI_RED, ANSI_GREEN, ANSI_YELLOW, ANSI_PURPLE, ANSI_BLUE, ANSI_WHITE, ANSI_BLACK, scanner01);
      System.out.println(ANSI_PURPLE + "\nKyle is currently sitting at the breakfast table, reminiscing over times he had milk for his cereal." + ANSI_RESET + "\n\nKyle can either: \n1:stay at the breakfast table.\n2:get up from the breakfast table.\n\n\n[enter '1' or '2'.]\n");

    String decision1 = scanner01.nextLine();

    while (true){     
      if (decision1 .equals("1")){
        System.out.println("option 1 chosen.");
        StayAtTable(inventory, money, ANSI_BOLD, ANSI_RESET, ANSI_CYAN, ANSI_RED, ANSI_GREEN, ANSI_YELLOW, ANSI_PURPLE, ANSI_BLUE, ANSI_WHITE, ANSI_BLACK, scanner01);
        break;
      }else if (decision1 .equals("2")){
        System.out.println("option 2 chosen.");
        GotUpFromTable(inventory, money, ANSI_BOLD, ANSI_RESET, ANSI_CYAN, ANSI_RED, ANSI_GREEN, ANSI_YELLOW, ANSI_PURPLE, ANSI_BLUE, ANSI_WHITE, ANSI_BLACK, scanner01);
        break;
      }else{
        System.out.println("wrong input, try again lol");
        decision1 = scanner01.nextLine();
      }
    }

    
  }
```

Unfortunately instead of printing purple it prints green. And in a following method, printing purple returns blue. Might be related to argument order? I'm not sure

I tried changing the order of arguments and a fair bit of other bullshit but nothing worked? It was meant to just print purple but it feels as if it just picks a random one lol

Comment: Take the [tour]. Read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and post a [mcve] so that I can reproduce your problem and, subsequently, try to find a solution. What platform are you on? Is it [Microsoft] Windows? Is it linux? How are you running your Java code? Are you running it from an IDE? Are you using an IDE? If so, then which one? Is it IntelliJ? Is it Eclipse? Did you try Googling for [java console colors](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+console+colors)? Did you see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println)?