# Making a log4j console appender use different colors for different threads

Tags: java, console, log4j

I am tracking down some concurrency issues and it would be very helpful to have the output lines from each thread in a different color when logging to a console. I am on OS X. Could this be done using a conversion pattern to output some control codes or would it need a custom appender? Anyone know how?

```
2011-10-21 12:14:42,859 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-9] DEBUG ...
2011-10-21 12:14:43,198 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-10] DEBUG ...
```

The lines for exec-9 and exec-10 should be in different colors.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can extend [`PatternLayout`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) and override [`format(ILoggingEvent)`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html#format(org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent)). There you could look at [`LoggingEvent.getThreadName()`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggingEvent.html#getThreadName()) to get some color based on the thread name (odd/even, maybe?).

In order to output color to the console, you'll need to use an [ANSI Escape Sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

For instance, to output a red text:

```
  "\u001b["  // Prefix - see [1]
+ "0"        // Brightness
+ ";"        // Separator
+ "31"       // Red foreground
+ "m"        // Suffix
+ text       // the text to output
+ "\u001b[m " // Prefix + Suffix to reset color
```

Here some examples:

- [`ColoredPatternLayout`](http://www.cafebabe.info/log4j/ColoredPatternLayout.html) implementation by Ingo Thon.
- [Colour-coded Console Logging with Log4J](http://blog.uncommons.org/2006/04/09/colour-coded-console-logging-with-log4j/) blog post.

Just to add, maybe you could also achieve this by setting in the MDC a variable "randColor" with a random ANSI color code, for instance, in a `Filter`, and using it in the `conversionPattern` of a standard `org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout`  in your log4j's console appender configuration:

```
<appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
               value="\u001b[0;%X{randColor}m ....... \u001b[m" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

[1] [What does "\u001B[J" represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801273/what-does-u001bj-represent)

Comment: I don't want to "damage" the output logs by adding all sorts of formatting to the log messages as the log messages go to files as well. I want this to be done by configuration of the logging system and only for the console logger.

Comment: "[...]different color **when logging to a console**[...]"

Comment: [Tips working on Macos Terminal] To get more colors you can do this : `\u001b[0;38;2;233;235;235m....your text....\u001b[m`
For details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code and search for `38;2;<r>;<g>;<b>` *found this thread while looking for colored text in Terminal and this post helped me so I share this little tips*

Answer (score 48):

You can use [`MulticolorLayout`](http://log.jcabi.com/apidocs-0.17.1/com/jcabi/log/MulticolorLayout.html) from [jcabi-log](http://log.jcabi.com/). Add this dependency to the project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcabi-log</artifactId>
  <version>0.17.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And then configure it in `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=com.jcabi.log.MulticolorLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%color{%p}] %c: %m%n
```

Same in `log4j.xml`:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="com.jcabi.log.MulticolorLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%color{%p}] %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

In this example, `%p` will be replaced by `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `ERROR`, etc. and then painted into the color that is relevant to the logging level. Besides that you are able to use your own colors or predefined colors, for example:

```
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] $color-cyan{%c}: %color-red{%m}%n
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] $color-0;0;31{%c}: %m%n
```

More documentation about [ANSI colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Comment: Added a more advanced example of log4j and a example output.  I'm quite pleased with this solution, and I wanted to save someone else having to deal with ansi colors, logging levels, conversion patterns colors and testing.  Tested in Ansi Console on Eclipse and ANSICON.

Comment: 0.15 is the current version.

Answer (score 4):

See PatternLayout, configuration property "highlight": https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout

[image: Description of the highlight property]