# Formatting slf4j to log message types with colors

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I am using slf4j for logging in my Java Application. It involves a lot logging and log monitoring. 
Sometimes it is really difficult to read and find information from logs when the entire log is printed in the black color with.
Just to make it more readable, is it possible to log the different kinds of messages in different colors? 
For example all Error level messages in Red color or a different font size and all Info level messages in blue color and a different font size.

Any suggestions or help is welcome.
Thnx.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you put the Name of you'r IDE. And you can ask how to map to Stderr instead of Stdout for Error messages.

Comment: The log file is a plain text file. There is no concept of color. However, you might be able to find something with which to view the log that can color code it for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions come to my mind. They are not colors, but alternative solutions:

1. In your File Appender configuration, you can configure the pattern to include the log level (error, warn, etc). Then you can grep the file, to filter messages by level.
2. You can configure two file appenders (for two separate log files) with different level threshold. For instance, one would log all the logs above debug level (so info, warn, error) into let's say logs.txt and the other would log only the errors logs into errors.txt

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to change colors of `slf4j` logging, because there are no formatters. SLF4J is a middleware between your application and some logging facility, for example, Log4j or Logback.

You can change colors in Log4j output, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848325/making-a-log4j-console-appender-use-different-colors-for-different-threads). I would recommend to use [MulticolorLayout](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log/apidocs/com/jcabi/log/MulticolorLayout.html) from [jcabi-log](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log/multicolor.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but all your suggestions are for getting colored output in the console. Since I need to collect the log files from multiple systems and analyse them, so i needed the log files to be colored.

Comment: "log files to be colored"? hm... :)

Comment: @Panshul To combine multiple log files into one try Otros Log Viewer https://github.com/otros-systems/otroslogviewer.  I've been using it for a few years to combine the logs of several Java-based Windows services.

Answer (score 5):

Something you have to bear in mind.

First, SLF4J is only a logging facade.  How the actual log message is handled depends on the binding it used.  Therefore your question is invalid, instead, you should quote which implementation you want to use (LogBack? Log4J? etc)

Second, "Coloring" is not something meaningful in most case.  For example, if you are referring a plain text log file, there is nothing that we can control the coloring because they are all plain text (unless your editor have special syntax highlighting built-in for your log message format).  It may be meaningful if you want to see the color in the console/terminal, or if you are outputting your log into file format that allow you to contain color information (e.g. HTML).

With these two idea in mind, here is my suggestion.

LogBack has built-in support for coloring http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#coloring in console output.  If you are looking for way to see color in console output, and you are allowed to use LogBack, this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am using Log4j and i need to collect the log files from different systems and analyse them.. so there is no use of getting a colored output in the console. I need colors in the log file.. but thank you for the suggestion, I will try the HTML output.

Comment: If you can write a plain text file with color inside, then you can expect that.  However, it is something that is unachievable.  You may write your own viewer which analyze your log message and do the formatting and display to you.  I bet if you are willing to do so. Using HTML plus some CSS maybe the way to go for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add next appender into logback.xml to colorize logs output:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d %highlight(%-5level) [%thread] %cyan(%logger{15}): %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using a colored `ConsoleAppender`, you could also color the statement itself.  Note this has limitations and may not work with all systems.  It worked well for internal projects, particularly when you want to log that a major task in a chain is complete or simply while debugging errors.

To quote [an external link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-log-console-in-color):

```
System.out.println("\u001B[31m" + "the text is red" + "\u001B[0m");
```

`\u001B[31m` is the ANSI code to color the output red and `\u001B[31m` is the ANSI reset command.

```
public class ColorLogger {
    
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ColorLogger.class);
    
    public void logDebug(String logging) {
        LOGGER.debug("\u001B[34m" + logging + "\u001B[0m");
    }
    public void logInfo(String logging) {
        LOGGER.info("\u001B[32m" + logging + "\u001B[0m");
    }
    
    public void logError(String logging) {
        LOGGER.error("\u001B[31m" + logging + "\u001B[0m");
    }
}
```

In your case, it sounds like you can try to write the contents of the aggregated log out and optionally color each statement by finding each string that concerns you.

This can alternatively just be done by printing it to an HTML page and using CSS selectively on your text.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can add color to your console output by using ANSI escape codes. These codes provide a way to manipulate the text appearance in the terminal, including changing the text color. However, keep in mind that not all terminals support ANSI escape codes, so make sure the one you are using does.

To print colored logs, you can create a helper method that appends the appropriate ANSI escape codes to the log messages. Here's a simple example of how to do that:

```
@Slf4j
public class ColoredLogger {

    // ANSI escape codes for text colors
    private static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
    private static final String ANSI_BLACK = "\u001B[30m";
    private static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
    private static final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
    private static final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";
    private static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
    private static final String ANSI_PURPLE = "\u001B[35m";
    private static final String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
    private static final String ANSI_WHITE = "\u001B[37m";

    // Log levels
    public enum LogLevel {
        INFO(ANSI_GREEN),
        WARNING(ANSI_YELLOW),
        ERROR(ANSI_RED);

        private final String colorCode;

        LogLevel(String colorCode) {
            this.colorCode = colorCode;
        }

        public String getColorCode() {
            return colorCode;
        }
    }

    public static void log(LogLevel level, String message) {
                log.info(level.getColorCode() + message + ANSI_RESET);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log(LogLevel.INFO, "This is an info message.");
        log(LogLevel.WARNING, "This is a warning message.");
        log(LogLevel.ERROR, "This is an error message.");
    }
}
```

In this example, we have a ColoredLogger class with an inner LogLevel enum that represents different log levels. The log method takes a log level and a message as input, and it prints the message with the corresponding color to the console.

Remember that the appearance of the colored text depends on the terminal or console you are using. Some IDEs might not fully support ANSI escape codes, so the output may not show colors as intended. However, when running the code in a supported terminal, you should see the colored logs.

[Console output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADNuP.png)

Answer (score -2):

I use filters for both logging level and package. This example comes from Spring boot application.properties

```
   logging.level.root=warn
   logging.level.org.springframework=warn
   logging.level.org.hibernate=warn
   logging.level.org.starmonkey.brown=DEBUG
```

This way I see only messages I want to see

Comment: Thanks!!! It works for me! I was googling for a couple of hours for `org.slf4j.Logger` before found it. It turns out that it is related to spring boot settings, not to slf4j logger. Thanks again!

Comment: This is unrelated to the original question!