# Logger uses same color for entire output

Tags: java, logging, netbeans, slf4j

I'm trying to set up `slf4j`.
When I simply print an information and an error, I get the following output:

```
FATAL:   [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(5)] INFO com.company.myclass - this is an information  
FATAL:   [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(5)] ERROR com.company.myclass - this is an error
```

Except of the words `INFO` and `ERROR`, there are similar, they even have the same color - red.

Is this really the desired output?
Shouldn't `INFO` have another color, so that one can keep them apart?

This is my code:

```
Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

log.info("this is an information");
log.error("this is an error");
```

---

I added this Maven dependecy: [SLF4J Simple Binding » 1.7.25](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.25).

Comment: Why do both use FATAL as a prefix?

Comment: BTW I doubt the logger is using any color, much more probable this is a feature of the IDE (like output to standaed error being always red, or when starting with FATAL...)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468141/formatting-slf4j-to-log-message-types-with-colors

Comment: @NAIT: I don't know it either.

Comment: I do not use netbeans, but there should be some setttings or preferences in any menu...

Comment: What log library are you using on top of slf4j ?

Comment: @NAIT: Please see my update. I only added this Maven import.

Answer (score 3):

You get the message in red because slf4j-simple uses by default the `System.err` as the default output when `logFile` is not defined `private static String LOG_FILE_DEFAULT = "System.err";` You can check it on [source code](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-simple/src/main/java/org/slf4j/simple/SimpleLoggerConfiguration.java).

If you want your messages to be printed in white you can specify your output using the following argument `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=System.out` in this case `System.err` will be replaced by `System.out`.

If you choose instead an other log library such as Log4j and provide a configuration file you'll notice that logs will appear also in white.