# How to display error message with some colors using slf4j logger?

Tags: java, slf4j

How to display error message with some colors using `slf4j` logger?
Any suggestion in this regard will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this similar SO question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848325/making-a-log4j-console-appender-use-different-colors-for-different-threads if your backend logging implementation is log4j.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change colors of `slf4j` logging, because there are no formatters. SLF4J is a middleware between your application and some logging facility, for example, Log4j or Logback.

You can change colors in Log4j output, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848325/making-a-log4j-console-appender-use-different-colors-for-different-threads).