# What does "\u001B[J" represent?

Tags: java

Can anyone explain to me what \u001B[J within a string might represent? I'm converting an input byte stream to an ascii string. Perhaps the stream is in some other encoding.

**UPDATE:**

This is how I read the stream

```
inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(session.getStdout(), "ASCII");

int length = inputStreamReader.read(buffer);
stringBuilder.append(buffer, 0, length);

// LOG the result
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: but where do you see this string?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That is Unicode `1B` (the `ESC` character), followed by the two characters `[` and `J`, an ANSI escape sequence common on many terminals.

That particular one clears the screen. Others can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Answer (score 1):

```
\u001B[J
```

means unicode

Unicode is stored in 2 bytes, so after \u there is 4x hexa bytes, in this case is `\u001B` The `[J` is from other