# How to make the log message in red color on console?

Tags: eclipse, logging, log4j

My log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, STDOUT, file

log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=mylogs.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

The log messages printed onto my console don't have any color. It should be at least red, right? How can I tweak my parameters to make it red appear on Eclipse console?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233790/colorize-logs-in-eclipse-console http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848325/making-a-log4j-console-appender-use-different-colors-for-different-threads?noredirect=1&lq=1